# Display a 2d histogram in pyqtgraph with correct axes

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm plotting a 2d histogram as image in pyqtgraph. I would like to set the axes scales correctly (i.e. representing the actual values of the binned data).

I found [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/ccrYl1yyasw/io4nTetaM7wJ) but I'm not quite sure how to translate it to my case.

I do:

```
h = np.histogram2d(x, y, 30, normed = True)

w = pg.ImageView(view=pg.PlotItem())
w.setImage(h[0])
```

but the scale of the `PlotItem` axes run from 0 to 30 (number of bins), which is not what I would like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the position and scale of the image. The link you provided has the following code:

```
view.setImage(img, pos=[x0, y0], scale=[xscale, yscale])
```

You only need to determine the correct values of [x0, y0] and [xscale, yscale] based on your bin values in h[1].